# iOS Automation Hybrid App Testing - How to address HTML DOM elements

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

I'm using iOS Automation to test a hybrid app.

I have two questions:

1. What logic is used by iOS Automation to generate the element names? From my `logElementTree()` it appears it is using the labels but sometimes the element name is (null) - see below. Why?
2. Is there a way to use the HTML control id to address the elements? For example if I have a text input like this:
   `<input id="myid" type="text"/>`, how can I set a value using `myid`?

Thanks!

```
UIAStaticText "*First Name" {{229, 253}, {84, 19}}
UIATextField "*First Name" {{614, 246}, {395, 32}}
UIAStaticText "*Last Name" {{229, 291}, {82, 19}}
UIATextField "*Last Name" {{614, 284}, {395, 32}}
UIAStaticText "Middle Initial" {{229, 329}, {84, 19}}
UIATextField "Middle Initial" {{614, 322}, {395, 32}}
UIAStaticText "5. Effective Date" {{229, 419}, {110, 19}}
UIAElement "(null)" {{615, 418}, {356, 28}}
```